# MySQL: Selecting Earliest Instance of Each Unique Combination of Two Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

For a table called *test_section* there are columns *topic*, *section_type*, *result*, *test_id* (FK).

*test_id* is the primary key of a table called *test*, which also has a column called *student_id* and *test_date*.

For a given *student_id*, I want to find every combination of *topic* and *section_type* and the *result* for that combination. When multiple instances of a combionation exist for that student, I want to return the *result* with a *test_id* corresponding to the earliest *test_date* (the initial result).

It can be assumed that each *test_id* will have a unique *test_date* and that a *test_id* will not be linked to more than one instance of any combination of *topic* and *section_type*.

What sort of query should I use here? As of now, I can only think of using multiple subqueries, but I ideally want the most efficient approach.

Comment: If using version 8.0, look into `row_number()`. You can simulate on older versions but not as pretty.

Comment: Please run the SQL query `SELECT VERSION();` and report what it shows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of)

Comment: Clearly this is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for MySQL 8.0+ using a window function:

```
SELECT topic, section_type, result
FROM (
    SELECT topic, section_type, result, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY topic, section_type 
        ORDER BY test_date) AS rownum 
    FROM test
    JOIN test_section USING (test_id)
    WHERE student_id = ?
) AS t
WHER rownum = 1;
```